# How to execute test case in telenium in the order I have defined

Tags: python, server, kivy, oserror

I am using telenium to automate the test of kivy application.
https://github.com/tito/telenium/blob/master/README.md

```py
def enable_server():
    def start_server():
        os.system('python server.py')

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=start_server, daemon=True)
    t1.start()
```

My Skeleton of the telenium testcases looks like this.

```py
class UITestCase(TeleniumTestCase):
    cmd_entrypoint = [" main.py"]

    def first_test(self):
         """code to test"""

    def second_test(self):
         enable_server()
         """code to test"""


    def third_test(self):
         enable_server()
         """code to test"""
```

Since two of tests need the enable_server() the application does not execute the third_test completely and fails. I am not sure why this is happening.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "node_sim.py", line 63, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 603, in _wrap_awaitable
    return (yield from awaitable.__await__())
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 1071, in __await_impl__
    server = await self._create_server()
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1378, in create_server
    % (sa, err.strerror.lower())) from None
OSError: [Errno 98] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 5000): address already in use
```

Comment: It clearly says `address already in use`?  Try `netstat -pnltu | grep 5000` to see the program using that port and kill it.

Comment: @ cmbfast. Since I am running the server code in thread, Could You please say how to kill it at the end of each function.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `enable_server` in `init` method. It will run before every UITestCase.

> Each new TeleniumTestCase will close and start the application, so you always run from a clean app. If you always need to do something before starting the test, you can overload the init. This will be executed once before any tests in the class starts:

[doc](https://github.com/tito/telenium#create-unit-tests)